# Nested FormArray in Angular Reactive Forms based on JSON

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms, formarray

I have JSON structured as follows...

```
data = {
  groups: [
    {
      name: 'Primary',
      people: [
         {
           name: 'Jordan',
           begCount: 23,
           endCount: 41
         },
         {
           name: 'Mike',
           begCount: 18,
           endCount: 24
         }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: 'Secondary',
      products: [
         {
           name: 'David',
           begCount: 23,
           endCount: 41
         },
         {
           name: 'Greg',
           begCount: 18,
           endCount: 24
         }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: 'Third',
      products: [
         {
           name: 'Josh',
           begCount: 23,
           endCount: 41
         },
      ]
    }
  ]
};
```

Based on the API call, this data could have different amounts and values of 'people'.  I am trying to use FormBuiler, FormGroup, and FormArray to create a reactive form and patch in the values from the data but am having trouble figuring this one out. Here is an image of what the UI would look like with the above returned data...

[image]

I have tried to create two instances of a FormGroup that each have an array but I could not get that to work. Just looking for some pointers as to how to set this up...not worried about the totals, I can figure that out once I am nesting the arrays properly.

My current HTML looks like this...

```
<form [formGroup]="groupForm">
  <table *ngFor="let group of data.groups">
    <thead>
      <th class="group-name">{{group.name}}</span></th>
      <th>Beginning Tally</th>
      <th>Ending Tally</th>
      <th>Total</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let person of group.people;  let i=index" formArrayName="people" [formGroupName]="i">
        <td><input type="text" formControlName="name"></td>
        <td><input type="number" formControlName="begCount"></td>
        <td><input type="number" formControlName="endCount"></td>
        <td><input type="number" disabled></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="grand-total">
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td class="total-label grey"><span>Totals</span></td>
        <td class="grey"></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: I'd create a component based on the "group" data that has all the data points. In the parent component, you add the component inside a *ngFor loo of "Groups" and pass the group to the child component. Since it looks like data is editable, the ngFor will be inside a form. Checkout https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: @EddiePaz Thanks for the response.  I have updated my question to include my html which shows how I am trying to structure the form with FormGroup and FormArray.  Any pointers on how to properly set up the formGroup and formArrays in typescript based on this structure?  Thank you.